# How can I load the content of the HubSection just when it becomes visible?

Tags: mvvm, windows-phone-8.1, windows-store-apps, windows-8.1

How can I load the content of the HubSection with Windows Phone 8.1 and Windows 8.1 HubControl just when it becomes visible?

I would like do this with the MVVM pattern.

Comment: Dynamically adding hub sections?

Comment: Lots of ways.  Which of them have you tried?  What's wrong with your code?  Please [edit] and provide details.

Comment: I would load the hubsection content only when it is visible on the screen. Load dynamically sections don't solve my problem.

Comment: @asitis I don't understand your suggestion.. I need an event raised when a section become visibile on the screen..

Comment: What you mean by visibility ? Are you loading from the rest service ? Please provide more clarification.

Comment: I don't want load all sections at pageload but I want load, for example, the last section only when the user scroll to it.

Comment: You can listen to SelectedIndex change in your ViewModel and then bind the Section VM inside the ContentControl inside your HubSection